# EntityFramework LazyLoading SaveChanges Bug

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

For example. There is a class named A.

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public virtual Guid Id {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public virtual B B {get;set;}
}
```

When I call this method it will throw exception that B can not be null.

```
public void Edit(Guid id, string name)
{
    A a = _DbSet.Find(id);
    a.Name = name;
    _DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

But this will success.

```
public void Edit(Guid id, string name)
{
    A a = _DbSet.Find(id);
    a.Name = name;
    B b = a.B; 
    _DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is this a bug of Entity Framework?

I use it with the version 6.1.

====================================

I found a regular that if a property link to a entity and it doesn't load from database then it will throw exception when you call `SaveChanges()`

Comment: You are getting entity A from the database and then editing the name property and then attempting to save. Is your database intact regarding the entity A which you are getting from the database in both cases?

Comment: Yes, they are intact. And this exception throw without regular. But if a method throw exception, it will always throw exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check the source code of Entity Framework. I found that the reason of bug is about `Validate` method of `ValidationAttributeValidator` class of EF assembly.

This method is call when a entity going to validate. And it will check any `Attribute` of `Property`. However, `RequiredAttribute` is not belong to EF assembly. `GetValidationResult` method of `RequiredAttribute` will not care about lazy loading of EF.

So, I think the solution is change the code of `Validate` method of `ValidationAttributeValidator` class. Ignore it if `Attribute` is `RequiredAttribute` and do something to validate property with lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug - it's a feature! You have specified `B` as `Required` but also `virtual`, which means it will be lazy loaded - in other words, it won't be loaded until you reference it.

So in your first example, you never load in `B`, so you get the exception. In the second example, you do reference `B`, which incidentally means another call to the database, and it gets loaded in.

You need to call `Include` to eager load `B`. Unfortunately, you can't use `Include` with `Find`, so try this instead:

```
A a = _DbSet.Include("B").SingleOrDefault(a => a.id == id);
```

Comment: Then that would defeat the purpose of lazy loading. What about if `B` also had a foreign key for `C`? You would end up loading all your dependencies unnecessarily.

Comment: I load `A` from database using `DbSet`, and I also load `B` from database. Then I change `Name` of `A` and `SaveChanges()`, it will success. It means that there is a `key` of `B` for property `B` of `A`. In an other word,  I save the `A`, EF should check is property `B` has value or has `key`. I think this is the turely lazy loading.

Comment: I mean that I load a `A` from database and I don't need to load 'B' from database. But EF doesn't allow me to save without `B` loaded. But when I load `A`, it also load a `key` of `B`. Why EF doesn't detect this `key`?

Comment: I don't know how you mean it is loading a `key`. `B` will be null until it is referenced or eagerly loaded in.

Comment: I mean EF make a class inherit `A`. And make some feature like a field named `_B` and type is `Guid`(If key of type of B is `Guid`). When I load `A`, `_B` will give a value that is the key of property `B`. And if EF has `_B`, why does EF need `B` has reference.